# WP + MySql db / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website running WP connected to a MySql db, where the latter uses PHP. I did not make the site and have only small experience with WP. This may be a simple question. The WP also uses Elementor. I interact with the db via  phpMyAdmin.

I have this page = http://linket.info/signup/
It accepts input data that does into the db.

See the labels ('First Name' etc). I can't seem to find them defined in WP. So they are in the db? I looked in the various db tables. But still can't seem to find these labels. Can you suggest what tables I might focus on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Scott and Milo's answers, you should take a look in the theme directory. If you browse the website file directory: /wp-content/themes/generatepress/
Look for a filename like page-template-signup.php

That said, since GeneratePress is a premium theme, you need to keep in mind if you make changes to that file, you will lose them when you update the theme.

The standard WordPress way around this problem is to use a child theme, which you can Google to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

If `/signup` is an actual WP page in the WP-admin under `Pages`, check if there is a template file in the theme (php) which would control the content form.

You will need to be able to access the php files via FTP in order to edit them, if you cannot edit the theme files within wp-admin directly. (not advised)

Comment: Indeed, if you look at page source, the body class contains `page-template-signup-php`.